# database image field passing null value

Tags: c#, database, winforms

How to pass `null` value to database field having type of image. I am trying this but getting an error:

```
if (photo)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EPhotograph",img);
else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EPhotograph", "");
if (signn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ESignature",sign);
else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ESignature",DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: What is the error you got? Please post it. Or may be the database column `ESignature` is not a Nullable column. Ensure it is not `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `DBNull.Value` please try to put empty byte array like this  `new byte[0];`

Reason SQL image type requires byte array as value in them.